# Category child of another category in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How to implement in rails a category that can be child of another category (self-referential has_one) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I believe you want a has_many relationship, not a has_one.  I can't imagine a situation where you would want categories to have at *most* one child category.  The previous answer also only gets you one direction - categories know about their parents, but not about their children.

The full solution is simple enough.  The categories table should have a category_id column, and the model should look like this:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :categories
end
```

If you want to go a step further and call them parents and children, you can:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => 'Category', :foreign_key => 'category_id'
  has_many :children, :class_name => 'Category', :foreign_key => 'category_id'
end
```

Good luck with your app!

Comment: Thank you, this worked pretty well. I was a bit confused on this association and your answer clarified it all :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The simple approach is to use a foreign key of `category_id` as others have already pointed out. However, if you're talking about nesting lots of categories this can be pretty inefficient. (Note: Posting more of your requirements would be helpful.)

I really, really like the [ancestry gem](http://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry). Here is a relevant snip from the docs (emphasis mine).

> As can be seen in the previous
>   section, Ancestry stores a path from
>   the root to the parent for every node.
>   This is a variation on the
>   materialised path database pattern. **It
>   allows Ancestry to fetch any relation
>   (siblings, descendants, etc.) in a
>   single sql query** without the
>   complicated algorithms and
>   incomprehensibility associated with
>   left and right values. Additionally,
>   any inserts, deletes and updates only
>   affect nodes within the affected
>   node’s own subtree.

And, here's a bonus freebie, just because it's not immediately obvious. If you need to treat siblings as a list with positions, you can scope them as follows.

```
acts_as_list :scope => 'ancestry #{(ancestry.blank? ? "IS NULL" : "=\'" + ancestry + "\'")}'
```

Comment: Thank you jdl, I'll look onto this but actually I have a pretty simple requirement to do category and subcategory of a simple system of products. I'll keep in mind this gem when I need more complicated structures like you said :) thanks for pointing me to it !